# Meteor: Select template conditionally based on url argument from controller

Tags: meteor, controller, iron-router

Hi I have this route

```
#CoffeeScript
    Router.route 'tests/:slug/:type/question/add',
      name: 'addQuestion'
      controller: testsAddQuestionController
```

And I have this controller

```
@testsAddQuestionController = testsQuestionsController.extend
  template: 'mcqQuestionForm'
  data: ->
    questions: TestQuestions.find()  
    test: Tests.findOne slug: this.params.slug
```

And I want to select template from controller depending the value of :type parammeter, I tried two ways:

```
@testsAddQuestionController = testsQuestionsController.extend
  template: if this.params.type is 'mcq' then 'mcqQuestionForm' else 'somethingelse'
  data: ->
    questions: TestQuestions.find()  
    test: Tests.findOne slug: this.params.slug
```

But with this approach I get the error `this.params is undefined`

Second approach

```
 @testsAddQuestionController = testsQuestionsController.extend
      template: if Router.current().route.params.type is 'mcq' then 'mcqQuestionForm' else 'somethingelse'
      data: ->
        questions: TestQuestions.find()  
        test: Tests.findOne slug: this.params.slug
```

But the applciation crashes with this approach, does any body know how to access to route parameters in order to make this conditionals for select template from controller?

Comment: Have you tried defining template as a *function* that returns the template name?

Comment: Hi thank you! I forgot to define template as a function, well below I is my answer, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how our controller looks like:

```
@testsAddQuestionController = testsQuestionsController.extend
  template: ->
    qType = Router.current().params.type
    if qType == 'practical'
      'practicalQuestionForm'
    else if qType == 'mcq'
      'mcqQuestionForm'
  data: ->
    questions: TestQuestions.find()  
    test: Tests.findOne slug: this.params.slug
```

For some reason (no idea why) if I save the current Router param into a variable and then use the variable for the if statement then it works.

Hope this helps you.